# Email fetching of listed users

Tags: php, email, gmail

I am fetching email of my `INBOX` at gmail. I want to fetch emails of those IDs only which I will give. I don't understand how to implement this.

When I tried doing it in the `imap_search` I didn't get any success, it was like -

```
$emails = imap_search($inbox,'rajeev@gmail.com');
```

but it gave me all the emails of the inbox.

Any suggestion to achieve I want?

My code is -

```
function connect_mail(){

    $hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
    $username = '***@gmail.com';
    $password = 'password'; 
    $inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die(t('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error()));   
    $emails = imap_search($inbox,'UNREAD');     
    $Msgcount = count($emails); 
        for ($x = 1; $x <= $Msgcount; $x++)         
        {   
            $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox, $x);            
            $title = $overview[0]->subject;
                        $struct = imap_fetchstructure($inbox,$x);
            $contentParts = count($struct->parts);
            if ($contentParts >= 2) {
                for ($i=2;$i<=$contentParts;$i++) {
                    $att[$i-2] = imap_bodystruct($inbox,$x,$i);
                }
                for ($k=0;$k<sizeof($att);$k++) {
                    if ($att[$k]->parameters[0]->value == "us-ascii" || $att[$k]->parameters[0]->value    == "US-ASCII") {
                        if ($att[$k]->parameters[1]->value != "") {
                            $selectBoxDisplay[$k] = $att[$k]->parameters[1]->value;
                        }
                    } 
                    elseif ($att[$k]->parameters[0]->value != "iso-8859-1" &&    $att[$k]->parameters[0]->value != "ISO-8859-1") {
                        $selectBoxDisplay[$k] = $att[$k]->parameters[0]->value;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (sizeof($selectBoxDisplay) > 0) {
                echo "<select name=\"attachments\" size=\"3\" class=\"tblContent\"    onChange=\"handleFile(this.value)\" style=\"width:170;\">";
                for ($j=0;$j<sizeof($selectBoxDisplay);$j++) {
                    $filename = $selectBoxDisplay[$j];
                    echo "\n<option value=\"$j\">". $selectBoxDisplay[$j]    ."</option>";

                }
                echo "</select>";
             }
            $strFileName = $att[$file]->parameters[0]->value;
            $strFileType = strrev(substr(strrev($filename),0,4));
            $fileContent = imap_fetchbody($inbox, $x, $file+2);
            $ContentType = "application/octet-stream";

            list($file_first_name, $extension) = explode('. ', $filename);


            if ($extension == ".jpg" || $extension == "jpeg" || $extension == ".JPG")
                $ContentType = "image/jpeg";
            if ($extension == ".doc")
                $ContentType = "application/msword";
            header ("Content-Type: $ContentType"); 
            header ("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$strFileName; size=$fileSize;"); 

            if (substr($ContentType,0,4) == "text") {
                echo imap_qprint($fileContent);
            } 
            else {
                echo base64_decode($fileContent);
            }           
}
}
```

Comment: ` I want to fetch emails of those IDs only which I will give` << what IDs? can you give us example?

Comment: @ariefbayu - I want to fetch those mails only which comes from like 2 users (abc@gmail.com & 123@gmail.com). As I am implementing this to run on regular basis, so I don't want to fetch all those mails which comes to INBOX. Though I will fetch the emails of around 25 users to my portal, who are register into it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you want to search emails from certain user that is still unread. Try this in your [`imap_search()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-search.php):

```
$emails = imap_search ( $mailbox, 'FROM "user@email.com" UNSEEN' );
```

The code above will loop for emails from user `user@email.com` that has `UNSEEN` flag.

**UPDATE, BASED ON COMMENT CHAT**

just before you do:

```
for ($x = 1; $x <= $Msgcount; $x++)         
{
    //long process here
}
```

you wrap it with one more checking:

```
$emails = imap_search ( $mailbox, 'FROM "user@email.com" UNSEEN' );
if(false !== $emails){

}
```

the end result would be something like this:

```
$emails = imap_search ( $mailbox, 'FROM "user@email.com" UNSEEN' );
if(false !== $emails){
    for ($x = 1; $x <= $Msgcount; $x++)         
    {
        //long process here
    }
}
```

Comment: Not working. As you can see I am checking the number of mails in the INBOX by $Msgcount = count($emails);
In all cases it's echoing the total number of mails residing in the INBOX.

Comment: Yes check it once..may be It's not working for me due to some other reason which I am not able to find out...

Comment: I used this but it's still entering into the for loop...did you check for for loop or just the number of mails ?

Comment: ok, I need clarification. What do you mean by entering `for loop`? is it not finding the result but still do looping? or is it got the result, but you don't want to loop? or something else?

Comment: then you should check the value of `$emails` first. If there are no emails, `$emails` will be `false`. You do `count(false)` will result `1`

Comment: I didn't get you..how should I implement this code so that for loop doesn't get start if there is no mails from specified users ?

Comment: I put -

$emails = imap_search ( $mailbox, 'FROM "rajeevk@gmail.com" ALL' );
if(false !== $emails){
    for ($x = 1; $x <= $Msgcount; $x++)         
    {
        //long process here
    }
}
else
{
  echo "No mails from this user";
}

And it worked :)

Thanks :)